# Django get children of parent on parent detail page

Tags: python, django, view, model

I'm trying to get access to the children of a model and list them on the parents details page. Here is how I have it set up...

Models:

```
class Destination(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField( null=True, max_length=60, blank=True)
      featuredimage = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to ='media/')
      location = PlainLocationField(based_fields=['title'], zoom=7, null=True, blank=True)

class Airport(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField( null=True, max_length=60, blank=True)
      city = models.ForeignKey(Destination, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Views:

```
def destination_detail(request, slug):
    destination = Destination.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {
    'destination': destination,
    'airport': Airport.objects.filter(city = destination.id),
    }
    return render(request,"destination/detail.html",context)
```

Template:

```
<h1>
    {{ airport.title }}
</h1>
```

It doesn't throw an error or anything but nothing is displayed. I have everything imported and set up correctly, I think I'm just missing on how to properly set it up in my views. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Airport.objects.filter(city=destination.id)` is a `Queryset` of `Airport`s, so a *collection*. You thus *iterate* over it. I would also advise to rename the variable to `airports`, since that hints that this is a collection of `Airport`s, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def destination_detail(request, slug):
    destination = get_object_or_404(Destination, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'destination': destination,
        'airports': Airport.objects.filter(city=destination)
    }
    return render(request, 'destination/detail.html', context)
```

and then render this with:

```
{% for airport in airports %}
    <h1>
        {{ airport.title }}
    </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put in the filter the next line?

```py
context = {
    'destination': destination,
    'airport': Airport.objects.filter(city_id=destination.id)[0]
}
```

or

```py
context = {
    'destination': destination,
    'airport': Airport.objects.get(city_id=destination.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have anything in {{airport.title}}
if you want to get the title of the destination you can do

```
{{ airport.city.title }}
```